# Passing arguments through several functions in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

This is a question related to best practice.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
def clean_text(text, idx):
   title = sqlalchemy.query("SELECT title FROM page_titles WHERE id = %s" % idx)
   return {title: text}

def scrape_webpage(idx):
   """ do some stuff here"""
   response = requests.get(link)
   return clean_text(response.text, idx)

def main():
   for idx in range(10):
      scrape_webpage(idx)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

The main problem I have with this code is there is some statefulness required (namely `idx`) which is just being passed through `scrape_webpage`. You can imagine if you have many functions before `clean_text()` is invoked, `idx` has to be passed through all of them without being used in any of them.

Is there a better way that `clean_text` can know the state of the loop without having it passed as an argument (and incidentally, through all of the functions which use it)? Perhaps generators or callbacks? Would appreciate an example.

Comment: It is only a mock- example, but your `clean_text()` takes 1 argument and `scrape_webpage()` is trying to pass it 2. Also, Python isn't a pure functional language. Sometimes simply using a global is the easiest way to implicitly pass state around.

Comment: Updated the example, thx

Comment: FYI technical term for that is tramp data http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335005/is-there-a-name-for-the-anti-pattern-of-passing-parameters-that-will-only-be/335013#335013

Comment: @JaredSmith less of a "technical term" and more informal jargon – mildly offensive too.

Comment: @AlexPetralia can you fix the code in `clean_text`? What are you `SELECT`ing? Syntax error in `return {title: text)}`.

Comment: Updated. Thank you for the term - definitely some terminology would be useful so I can investigate this more.

Comment: try `global idx`. This will make it available to all functions

Comment: I realize that global variables are a possibility. Are they the preferred method? Would a class with a class variable be preferred instead?

Comment: @naomik offensive in what way? Class discrimination? AFAIK term refers to the freight train hoppers from US 1920's (Great Depression).